# Force password in Firebase Google signin every time the user login

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am implementing [Firebase Google Signin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) in my Android application. But when the user taps on the login button the app authenticates with one of the already added Google accounts without prompting the password.

Would it be possible to prompt the password every time the user tries to log in?

Answer (score 2):

> But when the user taps on the login button the app authenticates with one of the already added google accounts without prompting the password.

That's why is called [One Tap sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-started), so you can sign in with a single tap. Using this approach, you don't have to choose the same account when signing in, as it's already known from the previous sign-in.

If you have already implemented [Firebase authentication with Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin), in order to be able to choose another account, then you have to revoke the access from Google as well as from Firebase. Because you tagged as a programming language Kotlin, then I recommend you read the following article:

- [How to authenticate to Firebase using Google One Tap in Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d)

And here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle). If you'll see some differences, between the article and the repo, that would be because I constantly update the project to the latest dependencies and add new fixes and improvements.

Comment: Hey Raneez. Have you tried the solution above, does it work? Can I help you with other information regarding this question?